# Can I directly read Kaspersky reports?

Tags: kaspersky, crystal-reports

Can I read a Kaspersky report file directly? I have access to the report.rpt and detected.rpt files, but it cannot be opened in a Crystal Report Viewer application.

I get the following error when trying to open the file using a Crystal Report Viewer.

> the rpt could be corrupt or it could be a security permission issue
>   Messasge=Load report failed

Comment: original size is 690KB and after zipped it is 56KB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suggests the file is corrupt.

An easy, non techy (but also not guaranteed) way to tell is to compress the file and see how much smaller the file is when compressed. This is NOT an exact science but, for example, if you had a 2gb file and it compressed to 2kb then this is a good indication.

In your case, since the .rpt file is 690kb but compresses to 56kb (approx 8%) it suggests there is nothing you can do (unless a tool exists to recover .rpt files).

Comment: Is there a way to restore the cleared report using KIS 2013?