# How to restore Kaspersky reports?

Tags: anti-virus, kaspersky

Is there a way to restore cleared Kaspersky reports in Kaspersky 2013 version? I [have recently cleared the reports](https://superuser.com/questions/520392/can-i-directly-read-kaspersky-reports) in my Kaspersky 2013 and now I need to recover some information from the reports.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this article which may help (although it is for Pure and you haven't stated which version of Kaspersky you're using).

```
Open the main application window.
Click the Backup and Restore button.

In the Backup and Restore window, click the Reports link at the top of the 
window.

In the Report window you can select:
        tasks type: Backup or Restore
        period you wish to get the report for: Day, Week, Month, Year, Entire 
period.  
Using navigation arrows you can select calendar dates, for example, you can 
create a report of events from 01.03.2012 to 01.04.2012

When the work with the report is over, in the Report window click the Close 
button.

Close the main program window.
```

http://support.kaspersky.com/8085

However, if you've deleted the data, then the data has gone. Unless you took a back up recently?